# R: Loop should return numeric element from string

Tags: r, string, loops, for-loop

I have a question how to write a loop in r which goes checks if a certain expression occurs in a string . So I want to check if the the expression “i-sty” occurs in my variable for each i between 1:200 and, if this is true, it should give the corresponding i.

For example if we have “4-sty” the loop should give me 4 and if there is no “i-sty” in the variable it should give me . for the observation.

I used

```
for (i in 1:200){
  datafram$height <- ifelse(grepl("i-sty", dataframe$Description), i, ".")
}
```

But it did not work. I literally only receive points. Attached I show a picture of the string variable. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqcT6.png)

Comment: "i-sty" is just a string with the letter `i` in it. To you use a regex pattern with your variable `i`, you need to paste together a string, e.g., `grepl(paste0(i, "-sty"), ...)`. I'd also recommend using `NA` rather than `".`" for the "else" result - that way the resulting `height` variable can be numeric.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]! Please make your example reproducible, read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: `x <- c("6-sty xxx", "4-sty yyyy", NA, "sty zzz", "32-sty xyz");
as.numeric(sub("^([0-9]+)-sty.*", "\\1", x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"i-sty" is just a string with the letter `i` in it. To you use a regex pattern with your variable `i`, you need to paste together a string, e.g., `grepl(paste0(i, "-sty"), ...)`. I'd also recommend using `NA` rather than `".`" for the "else" result - that way the resulting `height` variable can be numeric.

```
for (i in 1:200){
  dataframe$height <- ifelse(grepl("i-sty", dataframe$Description), i, ".")
}
```

The above works syntactically, but not logically. You also have a problem that  you are overwriting `height` each time through the loop - when `i` is 2, you erase the results from when `i` is 1, when `i` is 3, you erase the results from when `i` is 2... I think a better approach would be to *extract* the match, which is easy using `stringr` (but also possible in base). As a benefit, with the right pattern we can skip the loop entirely:

```
library(stringr)

dataframe$height = str_match(string = dataframe$Description, pattern = "[0-9]+-sty")[, 2]
# might want to wrap in `as.numeric`
```

You use both `datafram` and `dataframe`. I've assumed `dataframe` is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The code you proposed works very well with [, 1] for me.